# Logitech C922 microphone not working in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: logitech

I have a Logitech C922 webcam which works but the microphone doesn't work. Settings does detect the microphone but I still can't get any sound and the mic bars don't move.

I tested the device on a windows laptop and it works fine.

My mainboard is an ASUS ROG Strix Z490-i

The system controls do detect the microphone. It is not suspended.

Here is the output from pcmd list-sources

```
index: 44
    name: <alsa_input.usb-046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_57E99BBF-02.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 9049
    volume: front-left: 56928 /  87% / -3.67 dB,   front-right: 56928 /  87% / -3.67 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 9619 /  15% / -50.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 32000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    card: 4 <alsa_card.usb-046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_57E99BBF-02>
    module: 34
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C922 Pro Stream Webcam at usb-0000:00:14.0-9, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.2/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_57E99BBF-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "085c"
        device.product.name = "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
        device.serial = "046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_57E99BBF"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "front:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "256000"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "128000"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analogue Stereo"
        device.description = "C922 Pro Stream Webcam Analogue Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
    active port: <analog-input-mic>
```

Comment: https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-logitech-c922-pro-issues-with-ubuntu-21-04.36260/ Check this site guy had same problem, at the bottom of the question he says his was defective the new one works.

Comment: There's no solution there. The camera works fine, only the microphone doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check installing `pavucontrol`?

Comment: how is pavucontrol relevant to the microphone?

Comment: afaik `pavucontrol`, and `paprefs` are the most powerful gui audio applications in Ubuntu, unless you are up for installing `jack2`. The two of them combined let you do much of what you can do with CLIs like `pacmd`, `pactl`, etc.

Comment: Your source is good. Device is properly wired through Alsa & into pa. Pavucontrol stands for Pulseaudio Volume Control. The device should show up and be routable in that app. It will let you configure the stream that is already started, as is evident from the last 4 lines of your output...  and the 3rd from last device. Definitely the correct driver.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the results from Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:046d-085c), this device should work with kernel versions 5.8 and above. That said, there are a number of people who have reported it works with Ubuntu 18.04 after unplugging and reconnecting, so your mileage may vary.

With this said, there are two things you will want to confirm:

1. The webcam is being plugged into a USB3.x port (a USB 2.0 port will offer "some" of the functionality, but it must be plugged into a USB 3.x port to operate fully)
2. The volume in Alsa Mixer is properly set. You can check this by opening a Terminal and typing `alsamixer`. You will see a screen that looks like this:
   [image: AlsaMixer]
   Use the <kbd>⇠</kbd> and <kbd>⇢</kbd> keys to navigate left and right to the microphone, then use the <kbd>⇡</kbd> and <kbd>⇣</kbd> keys to change the volume.

This *may* resolve the issue for you, so long as you are using an up-to-date version of Ubuntu 20.04 or newer.

Comment: Ports on this board are 3.x. Unlugging it does not work.

Comment: The settings in alsamixer made no difference. The OS is up to date

Comment: The link only lists video drivers. The mic would need to connect via its own Alsa driver, wouldn't it?